# How to add static CSS to Dojo 7 application e.g. FontAwesome?

Tags: css, webpack, build, dojo2

I have a fairly basic Dojo 7 (Dojo 2) app built with the dojo-cli tool.  Now I'd like to add FontAwesome icons to it.  I have a Pro subscription so I have a zip file with various folders of css and web font files that I want to include in my project, then link to from index.html.  I believe the Dojo build process uses `webpack`, and my knowledge of it is extremely limited.

I can link to fontawesome CDN free version in `src/index.html` easily, which works fine:

```
<!link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

The Dojo 2 tutorial at https://dojo.io/learn/building/static-assets says I can put static assets in the `assets` folder, so I extract the zipfile to `assets/fontawesome-pro-5.15.3-web` and try to link to it in `src/index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fontawesome-pro-5.15.3-web/css/all.min.css">
```

My intention is to use FontAwesome in the traditional way, not using CSS Modules.

```
<i class="fas fa-question-mark"></i>
```

The dojo build process emits a large amount of "copying file blah.css" as it copies `assets` content to `output/dev/assets` and I see the FontAwesome files in `output/dev/assets/fontawesome-pro-5.15.3-web`, however the build gives:

```
Html Webpack Plugin:
  Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/fontawesome-pro-5.15.3-web' i  n '/home/username/go/projectname/src':
  Error: Can't resolve './assets/fontawesome-pro-5.15.3-web' in '/home/username/go/projectname/src'
  
  - compiler.js:79 
    [travesty]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:79:16
```

I notice that it's referencing relative to `/home/username/go/projectname/src`, and the original `assets` folder is one level above that in the source tree, so I also tried this relative path in `src/index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/fontawesome-pro-5.15.3-web/css/all.min.css">
```

But this fails differently:

```
Html Webpack Plugin:
  Error: /home/username/go/projectname/src/index.html:97
  module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "all.min.30RjDni8.css";
                   ^
  ReferenceError: __webpack_public_path__ is not defined
  
  - index.html:97 Object../assets/fontawesome-pro-5.15.3-web/css/all.min.css
    /home/username/go/projectname/src/index.html:97:18
```

I have very similar results creating an `assets/simple.css` file and linking to that with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/simple.css">` so this seems a generic problem with my understanding of `webpack`.

Should I be using the "static assets" approach with these FontAwesome files, and if so how do I fix this build situation, or should I be trying to use this third party CSS library as a CSS Module, and if so, how?

It may be to do with webpack's "publicPath" concept, see https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/ .. if so I'd presume I need to do something to my `.dojorc` to control the Dojo build's use of webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @agubler on the Dojo discord channel, the fix is apprently this simple:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/fontawesome-pro-5.15.3-web/css/all.min.css">
```

Builds and works fine.  Feels dirty to use an absolute URL like that so if anyone has a more meaty, explanatory answer to give, I'd be happy to mark that as the Answer instead of this :)